# Can I change the address of a pointer without manually copying the whole matrix?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I have a matrix defined with pointers and in a function the matrix is passed by reference; in the function I want the matrix to be changed to some other matrix (with one of the dimension being differente) and I would like not to realloc and copy the whole matrix with a for cycle (lot of data). I would like to know how to do it, my code looks something like:

```
double **matrix;
matrix = malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));
for(i=0; i<rows; i++){
    matrix[i] = malloc(columns*sizeof(double));
    }
...
my_function(matrix,rows, columns);
```

with the function being:

```
double my_function(double **matrix, int rows, int columns){
double **new_matrix
...
return new_rows /*the columns stay the same*/
}
```

EDIT: The number of rows get smaller but all the elements in the matrix get changed; I thought of two way to make this but I don't know if any of them is feasible:

1) Inside the function writing

```
matrix = new_matrix
```

Does it make it so that after the function has ended I can access new_matrix using matrix?

2) Inside the function writing some kind of nested loop to dealloc all of the column and then rows of `matrix` and then reallocating them with the new value of `new_matrix`; although this seem doable it is also very time consuming

Comment: _one of the dimensions being different_ Are you making the rows larger/smaller? Then `realloc` each row. This may or may not involve copying the data. Can you provide more details?

Comment: can either dimension be different? if the new matrix has fewer rows free the additional rows, if it has more rows allocate additional rows, if it has a different number of columns realloc all the rows as already suggested.

Comment: `matrix = malloc(rows*sizeof(double));` should be `matrix = malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));`. The `matrix` parameter in `my_function` should be type `double ***` if the function needs to reallocate it.

Comment: @IanAbbott I don't get the `double ***`

Comment: @Ringo_00 Since it is reallocating the rows, the `double**` pointer value may change. It needs some way to pass the changed `double**` value back to the caller. One way to do that is to pass a pointer to the `double**` variable to the function, i.e. a `double***` parameter. Another way is to pass the original `double**` value to the function and make the function return the updated `double**` value.